# Virtual Box OSX host, Windows 7 Guest Host-Only Network appears as Unidentified network

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm trying to set up communication between my guest Windows 7 and host OSX machines. I have virtualbox configured with a `vboxnet0` Host-only network with the following settings:

```
IPv4 Address: 192.168.21.19
IPv4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv6 Address:
IPv6 Network Mask Length: 0
```

and DHCP disabled.
I have my Windows 7 vm configured with Adapter 1 as a Bridged Adapter (that works correctly for internet access) and Adapter 2 as the `vboxnet0` Host-only Adapter.

On the Windows 7 vm I see two active Local Area Connections, `Network 2` (which I assume is the bridged one and looks to be configured correctly) and `Unidentified network` which I assume is supposed to be the Host-only. I've read a lot about fixing `Unidentified network` issues but all solutions rely on [editing a registry value](http://robboek.com/2008/12/18/vmware-unidentified-network-issue-in-vista-and-windows-server-2008-fix/) I do not have. Device manager on the Windows vm shows both adapters as `Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter` which is why I assume I cannot find the correct registry value to edit in order to fix the `Unidentified network` problem.

`ifconfig vboxnet0` on the mac returns:

```
vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00
    inet 192.168.21.19 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.21.255
```

`ipconfig /all` on the VM gives

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Pro-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-F1-F3-03
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5000:42b6:9cff:5d1%13(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.5.209(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 302514215
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-51-B1-EC-08-00-27-E6-26-5D
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 08-00-27-E6-26-5D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::bdc5:f6fa:e541:cdc8%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.223(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, August 26, 2015 4:26:45 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, August 27, 2015 4:26:47 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 235405351
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1D-51-B1-EC-08-00-27-E6-26-5D
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       4.2.2.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{6498E4F3-8CC9-4D50-BB63-F1D6C7FAD40C}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E6A74B05-7F4F-4D38-AF1B-AC517AF26AA9}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar Issue, and ended up solving it with a small trick.

- Go to control panel-> Network and sharing
- Select the host-only network connection, and go to properties (not details)
  **You'll notice no default gateway is configured.**
- Select Internet Protocol Version 4( for IP4 address) and select Properties again.
- Click on Advanced button and add a default gateway with the ip of the host in this host-only interface (the one that shows when you execute ifconfig in the host OS).
- Ok, Ok, Close, Close.

In my case it asked me what kind of network it was( I'm a  Windows noob, so selected Home Network and crossed my fingers ). Tried again to connect from host OS and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had to disable Cisco's VPNadmin Service and OpenVPN Service on my host. 
I did this by running msconfig and disabling these services "on Windows start".
Then I rebooted. 
Finally I had to DISABLE the "VirtualBox Host-Only Network Adapter" in my network connections panel.

If I now need VPN I have to start the services manually - but this is bearable for me.